# Can I have one service that exposes intranet and internet operations?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Assume I have a service that has about 10 operations, but 2 of them are needed for intranet purposes only.  How would I configure the two operations to be restricted only to the intranet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same WCF service can expose [multiple contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751424%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Put the internet operations in a seaparate interface and expose it using security settings that make sense for an intranet environment.

For example: Your internet operations could have an endpoint that uses UserName security and publishes the operations via a mex point. The intranet operations could have an endpoint that uses Windows based security and doesn't expose a MEX point.